# Add tax/vat to a live paypal buy now button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to add VAT to the price of the product, depenending on the status of the user. I have been working in paypal sandbox, and I have created two buttons, one where I specify a tax rate of 20% and one without a tax rate. So if the user provides a valid VAT number of an EU country I present him the button without VAT. All other users will have to pay VAT and use the buy now button that has the VAT rate.

For the first button I specify the tax rate from the button editor, like in the image below:

[image]

Now I want to transfer my application to the live paypal site. So I started creating the exact same buttons, but unfortunately only then I noticed that there is no option on the live site to add tax to a pay now button. It only has the option to specify postage:

[image]

Am I missing something? Is there another way to achieve this? I have also tried adding a paypal variable to the button html form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="20.00">
```

This didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can setup your sales tax rates in PayPal.

Below are two:

You can use this code in your button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="20.000">
```

Here is a link to additional button code fields that should be accepted:
[PayPal HTML Variables for Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)

Here is the other way you an setup sales tax through PayPal. Here is the PayPal Documentation about adding Sales Tax through PayPal.

PayPal won’t charge sales tax on your payments unless you select this option and specify a rate.

To select this setting on your account:

1. Log in to your account at https://www.paypal.com/.
2. Click ‘Profile’ near the top of the page.
3. Click ‘My selling tools’.
4. Under Selling online click ‘Update’ next to Sales tax.
5. Click ‘Add New Sales Tax’ in the Domestic or International section to add a new rate.
6. Enter the rate and click ‘Continue’.
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 for each new rate needed.